# Can Ruby on Rails 3.0 run on Mac OS X Leopard 10.5? (instead of Snow Leopard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

It seems that most of Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2 can be used, but when it is `sqlite3-ruby`, or `mysql2` gems, then it can't compile, (missing `mkmf`?) and the latest Xcode is needed.  But the latest Xcode is for Snow Leopard only.  So looks like the Macbook needs to be upgraded to Snow Leopard before Rails 3 can be used?

Comment: which version of xcode do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)? It provides an easy way to install different Ruby (and Rails) versions in your system. [This guy here](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/06/11/gem-install-mysql-on-mac-osx-leopard-with-rvm/) describes his experience with RVM, mysql and MacOS 10.5.

Hope it helps!

Comment: if installation of sqlite3-ruby doesn't work, having RVM doesn't help, does it?

Comment: The article at the link I provided describes how to install the mysql gem on Leopard. mkmf.log is mentioned and he uses RVM. I thought it could be relevant (I still do!)

Comment: the article is about mysql and not mysql2, but I almost positive I was able to install mysql2 gem before I upgraded my box to snow leopard and I think the same (or similar) methods were used for mysql2.  Can you update the question and post the exact error message you are getting when you try to install?

Answer (score 0):

It should work on Leopard without the new Xcode, get it with `sudo gem install rails`.